# LibGDX texture bleeding issue

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, texturepacker

I'm new to LibGDX and was trying to implement parallax background.
Everything went good until I faced such issue: I get some stripes when scrolling background. You can see it in attached image:

[image: Texture Bleeding]

So I looked deeper into an issue and figured out that this some sort of texture bleeding. But the case is that my textures already have [Linear, Nearest] filter set and TexturePacker uses `duplicatePadding`. Actually, I don't know any other methods to solve this issue. Please help!

Here's some of my code:

**TexturePacker**

```
TexturePacker.Settings settings = new TexturePacker.Settings();
settings.minWidth = 256;
settings.minHeight = 256;
settings.duplicatePadding = true;
TexturePacker.process(settings, "../../design", "./", "textures");
```

**AssetLoader**

```
textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("textures.atlas"));

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Background.skies.add(textureAtlas.findRegion("background/sky", i));
    Background.skies.get(i).getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Background.clouds.add(textureAtlas.findRegion("background/cloud", i));
    Background.clouds.get(i).getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    Background.cities.add(textureAtlas.findRegion("background/city", i));
    Background.cities.get(i).getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
}

Background.moon = textureAtlas.findRegion("background/moon");
Background.forest = textureAtlas.findRegion("background/forest");
Background.road = textureAtlas.findRegion("background/road");

Background.moon.getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
Background.forest.getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
Background.road.getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
```

**BackgroundDrawer**

```
private void drawParallaxTextureList(Batch batch, List<TextureAtlas.AtlasRegion> list,
                                     float moveX, float posY) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        boolean needDraw = false;

        float shift = GameScreen.VIEWPORT_WIDTH * i;
        float drawX = 0.0f;

        if (shift - moveX <= -(GameScreen.VIEWPORT_WIDTH)) { // If it's behind the screen
            if (i == 0) { // If it's first element
                if (moveX >= GameScreen.VIEWPORT_WIDTH * (list.size() - 1)) { // We need to show first after last
                    needDraw = true;
                    drawX = (GameScreen.VIEWPORT_WIDTH) - (moveX - ((GameScreen
                            .VIEWPORT_WIDTH) * (list.size() - 1)));
                }
            }
        } else if (shift - moveX < (GameScreen.VIEWPORT_WIDTH - 1)) {
            needDraw = true;
            drawX = shift - moveX;
        }

        if (needDraw) {
            batch.draw(list.get(i), (int) drawX, (int) posY);
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I don't use any camera for drawing right now. I only use `FitViewport` with size of `1920x1280`. Also, bleeding sometimes appears even in FullHD resolution.

**UPDATE:** Setting both `Nearest` filters for minification and magification with increasing `paddingX` and disabling antialiasing solved issue, but final image become too ugly! Is there way to avoid disabling antialiasing? Because without it, downscale look awful.

Comment: Does disabling antialiasing help if you leave the filter as linear? Why would you use antialiasing in a 2D game anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set both min and mag filters as **Nearest**

```
    .setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest, Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest);
```

In GUI TexturePacker there is an option to extrude graphics - it means **repeating every of border pixel** of texture. Then you can set both filters to Linear

```
    .setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
```

but unfortunately I cannot see this option in the TexturePacker.Settings object you are using. You can try to set Linear to both but I'm pretty sure it won't be working (Linear filter takes nearest 4 texels to generate the one so it will probably still generate issues).

Try to use GUI Texturepacker then with extrude option maybe

Comment: See for update in post, please. Setting both `Nearest` causes awful render quality on downscale.

Comment: I can't start this jar I found on google code on my mac. It says `Could not find or load main class texturepacker-gui.jar`

Comment: try this - https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/download. Free version should be enough for you since it has all option you need afaik. I'm using paid version and I recommend it

Comment: have you set Reduce Border Artifacts option? Please provide a screenshot of your settings in TP

Comment: There they are: [one](http://postimg.org/image/6f4c9iin1/) and [two](http://postimg.org/image/sd0t3axnh/)

Comment: I will compare it with mine settings when I will be at home but at first - I see that you have **extrude** = 0 when it shoud be 1 or 2, also change **trim mode** to none

Comment: Have you tried trim -> none and extrude -> 1 ? Because this is what I have in my TP settings. Everything else is the same as yours

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it became better but still had gasps on edges of sprites... :(

Answer (score 0):

A few possible reasons for this artifact:

1. Maybe the padding is not big enough when the sprite resolution is shrunk down. Try changing your texture packer's `filterMin` to MipMapLinearNearest.  And also try increasing the size of `paddingX` and `paddingY`.
2. Maybe you're seeing dim or brightened pixels at the edge of your sprite because you're not using pre-multiplied alpha and your texture's background color (where its alpha is zero) is white. Try setting `premultiplyAlpha: true`. If you do this, you need to also change the SpriteBatch's blend function to `(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` to render properly.
3. You seem to be rounding your sprite positions and sizes to integers when you draw them. This would work in a pixel perfect game, where you're sure the sprites are being rendered exactly at 1:1 resolution to the screen. But once the screen size does not match exactly, your rounding might produce gaps that are less than 1 pixel wide, which will look like semi-transparent pixels.

Comment: 1: not helping. Helps only with `Nearest` filter. Still have gasps on native resolution but OK on downscale. 2: not helping. 3: has no effect on both native resolution and downscale.